# Проблема с выводом названий портов (SerialPort)

Tags: c#

Хочу вывести все названия подключеных портов, но выводится только название 1го...

```
public void s()
{
    ManagementObjectCollection ManObjReturn;
    ManagementObjectSearcher ManObjSearch;
    ManObjSearch = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * from Win32_SerialPort");
    ManObjReturn = ManObjSearch.Get();

    foreach (ManagementObject ManObj in ManObjReturn)
    {
        // MessageBox.Show(ManObj["DeviceID"].ToString());
        MessageBox.Show(ManObj["Name"].ToString());
    }
}
```

---

К примеру если я вывожу их в `comboBox1`, то их там 5. Но такой метод мне не подходит, я получаю названия в виде COM1, COM12, COM15... А хочется как на коде вверху (COM1 = Communications Port и т.д)

```
SerialPort sp = null;
List<string> SP_list = new List<string>();
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    sp = new SerialPort();
    string [] a= SerialPort.GetPortNames();
    foreach (var ports in a)
    {
        SP_list.Add(ports);   
    }
    foreach (var port in SP_list)
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add(port);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод SerialPort.GetPortNames() читает значения из реестра -- см. [referencesource](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/sys/system/io/ports/SerialPort.cs,670).

---

```
// #r "System.Management"
using System.Management;

IEnumerable<string> comPorts() {
   var q = @"Select * from Win32_PnPEntity 
             WHERE ClassGuid='{4d36e978-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}'";
   using (var so = new ManagementObjectSearcher(q))
     foreach (var o in so.Get().OfType<ManagementObject>())
        yield return o["Name"].ToString();
}

foreach(var p in comPorts()) {
   // ...   
}
```